# Find last non-zero element's index in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to find the index of last non-zero element in pandas series. I can do it with a loop:

```
ilast = 0
for i in mySeries.index:
    if abs(mySeries[i]) > 0:
        ilast = i
```

Is there a cleaner & shorter way of doing it?

Comment: I have no idea about the pandas series. What is the type for the series? And could you please give an example? As far as I think, you could travel from the end to begin, and return when meet with a non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just came up with a few solutions.

A couple of ways it with generator:

```
max(i for i in s.index if s[i] != 0) # will work only if index is sorted
```

and

```
next(i for i in s.index[::-1] if s[i] != 0)
```

which is quite readable and also relatively quick.

Through numpy's `trip_zeros`:

```
import numpy as np
np.trim_zeros(s, 'b').index[-1]
```

which is slower than both of the @DSM answers.

---

**Summary:**

```
timeit np.trim_zeros(s, 'b').index[-1]
10000 loops, best of 3: 89.9 us per loop

timeit s[s != 0].index[-1]
10000 loops, best of 3: 68.5 us per loop

timeit next(i for i in s.index[::-1] if s[i] != 0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.4 us per loop

timeit max(i for i in s.index if s[i] != 0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 16.8 us per loop

timeit s.index[s.nonzero()[0][-1]]
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.94 us per loop
```

Answer (score 9):

I might just write `s[s != 0].index[-1]`, e.g.

```
>>> s = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,0,4,0],index=range(7,14))
>>> s
7     0
8     1
9     2
10    3
11    0
12    4
13    0
dtype: int64
>>> s[s != 0].index[-1]
12
```

Originally I thought using `nonzero` would make things simpler, but the best I could come up with was

```
>>> s.index[s.nonzero()[0][-1]]
12
```

which is a lot faster (30+ times faster) for this example but I don't like the look of it.. YMMV.

Comment: `s.nonzero()` no longer works. One can use `s.to_numpy().nonzero()` instead