# Return the index of the last element in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I want to return the index of the last element of a pandas series. I've been looking at [SO entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000882/find-last-non-zero-elements-index-in-pandas-series), but none of the solutions worked.

I tried

```
 last_element=df.index[-1]
```

and

```
 last_element=df[-1].index
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample for explain, why not working?

Comment: Then `df[-1].index` should do IIUC?

Comment: Could you post the error messages (if you get any), or the "wrong" results you are getting using the methods mentioned in your question? The first method seems to work well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 df.last_valid_index()
```

Works for me.

Edit:

To store last element you can use `iloc`

```
last_element = df.iloc[-1:]
```

Comment: [`DataFrame.last_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html) - Return index for last non-NA/null value. - it is somethibng else like need OP

Comment: @cheesus - exactly, answer is really bad for general data with mising values, not use it.

Comment: all is wrong, OP need `I want to return the index of the last element of a pandas series. `

Comment: yes, in my case there won't be a nan value at the last row ever :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df[-1].index
```

Comment: Try creating a `pd.Series` like this: `s = pd.Series({0:1}); s.append(pd.Series({0:2}))`

Comment: If your series has an index, then `df[-1].index` should work. Show the head of your series or any error that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `tail()` function with the argument `1` (you want one element from the end, or the last element), and `index[0]` on this, which returns the index of the element.

`df.tail(1).index[0]`

Check out this post for more details: [index](http:///https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327624/find-elements-index-in-pandas-series)
And this one for info about `tail`: [tail function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tail.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know you said it didn't work for you, but really the way I usually retrieve the last index is with `df.index[-1]`. I tested it and it works both for DataFrames and Series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[1,4,5,3,3,5,6,7,8,9,5,4,2], 
                        'col2':[1,4,5,3,3,5,6,7,8,9,5,4,2]})

df.index[-1]
>> 12
```

And

```
df = pd.Series([1,4,5,3,3,5,6,7,8,9,5,4,2])

df.index[-1]
>> 12
```

If this doesn't work, can you tell us more about the errors you are getting?