# How to get the column name of last non zero value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data with some sequential features which must come before other feature comes.
I would like to get the final page visited by the user.

## Setup

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'user': [10,15,17],
                  'sex': ['M','M','F'],
                  'home_page': [1,1,1],
                  'search_page': [1,0,1],
                  'confirmation_page': [1,0,0],
                  'payment_page':[1,0,0]})
print(df)

   user sex  home_page  search_page  confirmation_page  payment_page
0    10   M          1            1                  1             1
1    15   M          1            0                  0             0
2    17   F          1            1                  0             0
```

## Question

How to get new column with name 'final_page' that have the name of final page visited.

Required answer

```
df['final_page'] = ['payment_page','home_page','search_page'] # this is not answer,
# The new column should have these values.
```

## my attempt

```
a = df.iloc[:,2:].to_numpy()
np.trim_zeros(a)
```

## realted links

[Find last non-zero element's index in pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000882/find-last-non-zero-elements-index-in-pandas-series)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'user': [10,15,17],
                  'sex': ['M','M','F'],
                  'home_page': [1,1,1],
                  'search_page': [1,0,1],
                  'confirmation_page': [1,0,0],
                  'payment_page':[1,0,0]})
pages = df.columns[2:]

df['final_page'] = df.iloc[:,2:].apply(lambda x: pages[np.max(np.nonzero(x))],axis=1)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   user sex  home_page  search_page  confirmation_page  payment_page  \
0    10   M          1            1                  1             1   
1    15   M          1            0                  0             0   
2    17   F          1            1                  0             0   

     final_page  
0  payment_page  
1     home_page  
2   search_page
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) product of columns with condition where `df!=0` and then split and get the last column:

```
m=df.set_index(['user','sex'],append=True)
df['final_page']=(m.ne(0).dot(m.columns+ ',').str.rstrip(',').str.split(',')
                                     .str[-1].droplevel(['user','sex']))
print(df)
```

Or:

```
df['final_page']=m.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index,axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
   user sex  home_page  search_page  confirmation_page  payment_page  \
0    10   M          1            1                  1             1   
1    15   M          1            0                  0             0   
2    17   F          1            1                  0             0   

     final_page  
0  payment_page  
1     home_page  
2   search_page
```

Comment: Thank a lot. Happy new year.

Comment: @MilkyWay001 happy new year in advance :) Happy coding